# Problem with Exact Word text search In MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to query a text entry in mongodb (3.6) using this code:

```
collection.aggregate([{$match:{$text:{$search: "gram"}}}])
```

in this query, results like this would be returned:

```
[{content:"Telegram is a messaging ...",tags:"Telegram"}, 
{content:"Instagram is a social ..." tags:"Instagram"}, 
{content:"gram is a unit of weight", tags:"gram"},
{content:"Mobogram is a shell for telegram", tags:"Mobogram"}]
```

but the desired result is:

```
{ontent: "gram is a unit of weight",tags:"gram"}
```

which means we are looking for exact matches. How would I change the query to get the exact matches?

Edit:

The index is:

```
weights:{contents:1, tags:1}
default_language:english
language_override:language
```

which was created with this:

```
collection.createIndex( { "content": 1, "tags": 1 } )
```

Comment: How was the text index created? What's the exact structure of the resulting documents (only the relevant part suffices, i.e. the fields that are part of the index)?

Comment: I edited the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a specific phrase is:

```
   { $text: { $search: '\"gram is a unit of weight\"' } }
```

Unfortunately searching for an exact match on a word is not really possible, this is due to mongo's use of [snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/) to stem and index words.

you can however try to match above a certain meta score on your text searches.

Example:

Assume we have 2 documents with a text field, once with the word sleep and the other with the word sleeping.
While creating the text index mongo saves the term "sleep" for both words.
Thus once i go searching for the term sleep even if i add the exact match syntax both will return as matches due to the nature of the indexing.

a cute tip to understand how mongo parses certain words is to run:

```
model.find({$text: {$search: 'sleeping'}}).explain()
```

this will return a JSON in the winningPlan object:

```
{
  "terms": [
    "sleep"
  ],
  "negatedTerms": [],
  "phrases": [],
  "negatedPhrases": []
}
```

now it is easy to understand which terms will match this search.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem but it actually worked for me... I created a couple of document with `text` field with the content OP provided and then created a text index with default settings on that field. `$match:{$text:{$search: "gram"}}` aggregate stage provided the correct result, i.e. worked as an exact word match. Tested with MongoDB 4.0.3

Comment: Again this depends on how mongo stems the word, for example if i have 2 documents with the words sleep and sleeping. once i search for either sleep will always get both due to the way mongo index's these terms.